# Bool assignment operator

Tags: c++, operators, boolean

I have a method where I create objects on the heap and return a boolean which indicates if it went well or not.
I am not 100% sure about my bool assignments though in (1); is this legal to do?

```
    bool ret = true;

    if (ret = !mRenderBackend)     // make sure mRenderBackend is NULL
    {
        if (mEngineSettings.GetRenderBackend() == OPENGL)
            ret = mRenderBackend = mMemoryAllocator.AllocateObject<RenderOpenGL>();    // (1). AllocateObject returns either NULL or object address
        }

    return ret;
```

Thanks

Comment: Even if this works, you are obscuring the logic. Test for NULL (or nullptr in newer c++).

Comment: If you don't want warnings on some compilers, use `if ((ret = !mRenderBackend))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need the bool at all, it sort of makes it harder to follow. I would personally do something like,

```
if (mRenderBackend == NULL)     // make sure mRenderBackend is NULL
{
    if (mEngineSettings.GetRenderBackend() == OPENGL)
        mRenderBackend = mMemoryAllocator.AllocateObject<RenderOpenGL>();    // (1). AllocateObject returns either NULL or object address
    }

return (mRenderBackend != NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, legal.

```
if (ret = !mRenderBackend)
```

is equivalent to

```
ret = !mRenderBackend;
if(ret)
```

is equivalent to

```
ret = (mRenderBackend == 0);
if(ret)
```

Just note that `ret` will only be defined up to zero/nonzeroness which looks safe in your code.